# Gnuplot transform x axis data with in the plot

Tags: transform, gnuplot

I have data in this format

```
apple 1

bananna 3

ornage 5

fig 4
```

I want the x axis data to appear in the plot and not in the axis as such. Moreover they are words and not numbers.

How can I do it please?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear.  Where do you want the labels to show up?  Here's an example where I'll put the label "apple" at the point (0,1) and the label "banana" at the point (1,3), etc. (each label is moved 1 unit further down the x axis):

```
plot 'data.dat' using (column(0)):2:1 with labels
```

You can also put points associated with it:

```
plot 'data.dat' using (column(0)):2 w p,\
             '' using (column(0)):2:1 w labels
```

Here the labels sit directly on top of the points.  That may not be what you want -- You can add an offset:

```
plot 'test.dat' u (column(0)):2:1 w labels offset character 0,1,\
             '' u (column(0)):2 w p
```

From the documentation (`help labels`), it appears that the appearance of your labels should be able to be modified by pretty much any option that you can pass to `set label`.

> The font, color, rotation angle and other properties of the printed text
>    may be specified as additional command options (see `set label`).